# Dirichlet Regression using Caret package

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret, dirichlet

I am attempting to predict tree species composition using Sentinel 2A imagery and forest plot data.  I have calculated the proportion of basal area (the cross-sectional area trees of a given species occupy within the plot divided by the total cross-sectional area all tree occupy with in a plot) from the forest plot data and want to predict proportion of basal area by species across the landscape as a raster using the intensity values from Sentinel 2A.  Dirichlet regression seems appropriate here, because I have more than 2 categories of proportional data bounded on (0,1) where the summed proportions for each observational unit must be equal to 1.  Therefore, I want to model the joint composition of proportional basal area as a function of spectral reflectance intensity using Dirichlet regression, with k-folds crossvalidation using 10 folds and 5 repeats.  This seems like a modeling exercise perfectly suited to `caret::train()`  using a custom function.
I followed the documentation for how to build a custom routine for `DirichletReg::DirichReg()`, but I am a bit stumped on how to feed a multivariate response variable to `caret::train()`.  The `DirichletReg::DirichReg()` function requires that response variable be formatted with the `DirichletReg::DR_data()` function first prior to modeling.  However, when I feed a `Dr_data` object to `caret::train()`, I get this error:

```
Error: wrong model type for classification
```

I think this error is getting thrown because I have passed a multivariate response variable to the `y=` argument of `caret::train()` and the routine thinks that can only happen with classification algorithms.  Does anyone have experience doing multivariate regression?  Is there another way to change my custom routine so that `caret::train()` will accept multivariate response variables?

Below is my reproducible example:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(caret)
library(DirichletReg)

##Creating Fake Data##
set.seed(88)#For reproducibility

#Response variables#
PSME_BA<-rnorm(25,50, 15)
TSHE_BA<-rnorm(25,40,12)
ALRU2_BA<-rnorm(25,20,0.5)
Total_BA<-PSME_BA+TSHE_BA+ALRU2_BA

#Predictor variables#
B1<-runif(25, 0, 2000)
B2<-runif(25, 0, 1800)
B3<-runif(25, 0, 3000)

#Dataset for modeling#
df<-data.frame(PSME=PSME_BA/Total_BA, TSHE=TSHE_BA/Total_BA, ALRU2=ALRU2_BA/Total_BA,
               B1=B1, B2=B2, B3=B3)

##Creating a Dirichlet regression modeling routine to feed to caret::train()##
#Method list#
Dreg <- list(type='Regression', 
             library='DirichletReg',
             loop=NULL)

#Parameters element#
prm <- data.frame(parameter=c("model"),
                  class="character")
Dreg$parameters <- prm

#Grid element#
DregGrid  <- function(x, y, len=NULL, search="grid"){
  if(search == "grid"){
    out <- expand.grid(model=c("common", "alternative"), stringsAsFactors = F) # here force the strings as character,
    # othewise get error that the model arguments
    # were expecting 'chr' when fitting
  }
  out
}
Dreg$grid <- DregGrid

#Fit element#
DregFit <- function(x, y, param, ...){
  dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
  dat$.outcome <- y
  theDots <- list(...)
  modelArgs <- c(list(formula = as.formula(".outcome ~ ."), data = dat, link=param$model, type=param$type), theDots)
  out <- do.call(DirichletReg::DirichReg, modelArgs)
  out$call <- NULL
  out
}
Dreg$fit <- DregFit

#Predict element#
DregPred <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc=NULL, submodels=NULL){
  if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
  DirichletReg::predict.DirichletRegModel(modelFit, newdata)
}
Dreg$predict <- DregPred

#prob element#
DregProb <- function(){
  return(NULL)
}
Dreg$prob <- DregProb

##Modeling the data using Dirichlet regression with repeated k-folds cross validation##
trCrtl<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5)
Y<-DR_data(df[,c(1:3)])#Converting the response variables to DR_data format
mod<-train(x=df[,-c(1:3)],Y, method=Dreg,trControl=trCrtl)#Throws error
```

Comment: I get: `Error in DR_data(df[, c(1:3)]) : could not find function "DR_data"`. I seriously doubt that you get the error you posted with that exact code. I think you made some sort of error in posting. You apparently put a parenthesis where it wasn't supposed to be. ALSO, I would have expected the "Y" argument to be a single column rather than three columns and that is certainly what the `Dreg` function expected when I tried just giving `df[,c(1:3)]` to Y as an argument,

Comment: Hi IRTFM, I just tried running the code copied and pasted from my post on a different machine and it works as described in my question and with the same error I originally posted.  Do you perhaps need to install the `DirichletReg::` package?  Yes, the three column issue is kind of at the heart of my question.  Dirichlet regression work with multivariate responses, not a single response variable, thus necessitating a multicolumn matrix.  Where was the misplaced parenthesis?

Comment: Apologies. I did have the package installed but I must have run the code without loading it. I'll see if I can work out the correct method.

Comment: The parameters need to be three in number. I think you may need to add `class="character"` if 'model" is a correct specification for parameter. But I thought the tuning parameter ought to be numeric. Having a dichotomous tuning parameter just doesn't "sound right".

Comment: Well after a bit more scouring it seem like `caret::` simply doesn't allow multivariate response regression. https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/466

Comment: That is a very helpful link. I think Max is now working at Rstudio and says this might be available in pkg::tidymodels

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out how to implement this in `tidymodels::` I think that will be the solution.  Some of it is a bit over my head, but I will post another reprex if I figure it out